# Sql resets my pooling connections after idle time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using a client pc and  i'm connecting via tcp/ip into a local database server. For some reason, after my connection will be idle for a while, then Sql keep alive is checking my tcp connection if it's still active. If the time when  keep alive is checking my connection and  tcp/ip traffic is high or other reasons, then it resets my connection inside pooling. So the result is that if my connection will be reset ,the first connection which  client pc  will try to run, it will get exception "TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
"  or " Server closed the connection" or something like this. This happens cause client pc will try to connect in a session which there is not exist inside sql pooling. I have set min pool size =10. But i still have the same problem.

[image]

after keep alive time
[image]

Here is my connection string

```
Data Source = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Min Pool Size=20; Initial Catalog = WiOrder; user id = xxxx; password = 1234;Connection Timeout=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not terminate connections.  What you are seeing is being done by the .Net driver on your client machine and is completely normal and expected behavior.

Please see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#removing-connections

Comment: But how can i solve this? Or how can i check if client's current connection is still active? If not create a new one else reconnect. Also Sql sends Rst package in my client application.